# Trying to clear the arraystack and getting a segmation error?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, game-development, tetris

So starting off here's the thing. 
I'm not experienced enough nor do I have enough time to make it as efficient to have it pop out on a different window.

2nd I don't also have enough time to add the other variables or have it rotate since the segmentation fault wasn't the only error. sometimes it would print the | on top of nothing because there's a shape under it. But it doesn't print out the shape.

Also, I have to use an array stack and linked list so there's no way for me to not use those 2. The main issue I'm trying to fix is When the code gets to the clear row1 then it just gives a segmentation fault. But why, I think I'm doing everything right.

Here's rest of my code:
https://repl.it/@AbbasZaidi/Final

```
bool RowFull(ArrayStack<string> &givenRow) {
bool Full=true;
string Given=givenRow.top();
for(int i=0;i<Given.length();i++)
{
    if(isspace(Given[i]))
    {
        Full=false;
    }
};
return Full;
}
void Board1Redo(tetris &a,ArrayStack<string> &bottomrow,ArrayStack<string> &row1,ArrayStack<string> &row2,ArrayStack<string> &row3, ArrayStack<string> &row4, ArrayStack<string> &row5, ArrayStack<string> &row6, ArrayStack<string> &row7, ArrayStack<string> &row8, ArrayStack<string> &row9,string &rowa,string &rowb,string &rowc,string &rowd,string &rowe,string &rowf,string &rowg,string &rowh,string &rowi, string &block1,string &block2,string &check, int &x,int &c) {

            while(!gameOver(row9)){
            cout<<"starting board1Redo"<<endl;
            if(RowFull(row1))
            {
                cout<<"row1 is full"<<endl;
                row1.clear();
                row1.push("#          #");
            }
            if(RowFull(row2))
            {
                cout<<"row2 is full"<<endl;
                row2.clear();
                row2.push("#          #");
            }
            if(RowFull(row3)) {
            cout<<"row3 is full"<<endl;
                row3.clear();
                row3.push("#          #");
            }
            if(RowFull(row4))
            {
                cout<<"row4 is full"<<endl;
                row4.clear();
                row4.push("#          #");
            }
            if(RowFull(row5))
            {
                cout<<"row5 is full"<<endl;
                row5.clear();
                row5.push("#          #");
            }
            if(RowFull(row6))
            {
                cout<<"row6 is full"<<endl;
                row6.clear();
                row6.push("#          #");
            }
            if(RowFull(row7))
            {
                cout<<"row7 is full"<<endl;
                row7.clear();
                row7.push("#          #");
            }
            if(RowFull(row8))
            {
                cout<<"row8 is full"<<endl;
                row8.clear();
                row8.push("#          #");
            }
            if(RowFull(row9))
            {
                cout<<"row9 is full"<<endl;
                row9.clear();
                row9.push("#          #");
            }
                Board1Redo(a, bottomrow, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, rowa, rowb,rowc,rowd,rowe,rowf,rowg,rowh,rowi,block1, block2,check, x, c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please debug your own code, narrow down the issue and create a [MRE]. You cannot just dump all of your code here and go "I have a problem, please fix it for me"

Comment: @bolov oh ok sorry, haven't used this a lot so I didn't know which parts of my code you need to see. Does this work?

Comment: I'm not clicking an anonymous link to see what surprise I get at the other side. If it's not in the question, it doesn't exist. If the code is not guaranteed to be there in ten years to help future programmers, the question becomes useless. Read the [mcve] link. It's a powerful Divide And Conquer-based debugging technique.You make a good MRE and most of the time you don't need to ask the question because you find the answer in the process. If you don 't find the answer, odds are the question really is a good one worthy of archiving.

Comment: Looks like you have a non-terminating recursion.

Comment: That function has an immense amount of parameters, and you're only using nine of them. And you could stick those nine in a list or other collection and only have one.

Comment: @molbdnilo oh no, it does stop at the game over so that's not the issue

Comment: Aha, that's not the entire function. This is the most repetitive code I've ever seen, and I've been programming for decades. It looks like you've completely missed the point of using collections and loops, and it's almost impossible to determine where a bug might lurk in all that code.

Comment: @molbdnilo I used all of them but gave a snippet since I tried to do minimally reproducible. You can really tell I've been here a lot since I'm having trouble asking a question lol

Comment: @molbdnilo Anyway, what do you mean the point of using collections and loops? sorry never heard about collections. what it does is goes down then it hits the most bottom row it can go till and as long as there's no game over It should make a shape at the top again. I tried doing a Tetris game for my final project. like any other game, shouldn't it be repetitive, you don't know when the guy will have a game over

Comment: Collections are things like arrays, vectors, and lists. You must have used some of them at some point, and most likely also iterated over one in order to do the same thing to all the elements.